# backbutton event is not been fired in phongap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap, but I have a problem in handling backbutton event. My code is,

I have device ready in my index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        parsePlugin.initialize("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", function(){
            //nothing required to do
        }, function(e){
            alert('Unable to Initialize Parse!');
        });
        parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("deviceToken", id);
        }, function(e) {
            alert('Unable to get DeviceToken!');
        });

        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        window.location = "main.html"
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {

    }
};

app.initialize();
```

my this index.js redirects me to the page main.html, where I have this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        function onBackKeyDown(e) { 
            alert('back button triggered'); 
            console.log(e); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false; 
            }
    </script>
```

Please guide me where is my mistake, why I am not getting the backbutton event.

Comment: you have to listen for the device ready on main.html too and put the document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); there too, and main.hmlt should link the cordova.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for this event first:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady{
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        function onBackKeyDown(e) { 
            alert('back button triggered'); 
            console.log(e); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false; 
            }
        }
    </script>
```